# Admob Implementation when iAd fails

Tags: objective-c, admob, iad

In my app, Admob banners are displayed only when iAd fails. I have tested it on my device by running the method that forces iAd to fail and it works fine, but Apple rejected my app because even though I implemented the AdSupport frameworks and the like, they say that there are no Admob banners. I don't know what else to do. Any ideas? The app is a simple game where the user must choose the correct answer out of 4 options before time runs out.Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.bannerView removeFromSuperview];
    _admobBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,     GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
    self.admobBannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-MY ADMOB ID";
    self.admobBannerView.rootViewController = self;
    self.admobBannerView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.admobBannerView];
    [self.admobBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

Here is the rejection letter: Thank you for your prompt response and providing detailed information about your app.

iAd does not use the AdSupport framework, ASIdentifierManager, or the Advertising Identifier. Therefore they are not required for iAd implementations and should not be included in your app for iAd support.

Additionally, upon review, the app did not display and Admob banner features. It may be necessary to appropriately implement ad functionality within the app before resubmission.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the behavior of your app, and the message apple gave you on it's rejection?

Comment: Sorry about that. I added a short description at the top (let me know if you need more) and the rejection letter at the bottom @StevenOjo